# SKTextureAtlas and 3x images

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, xcode6

Has anyone been able to get the simulator in xcode 6 to use the 3x images inside of an atlas?  Whenever I load them into SKTextureAtlas it will use the 2x image instead.

if i put test@2x.png, and test@3x.png inside of an atlas, my iphone 6 / plus simulator will always use the 2x image.

```
let texture = shipAtlas.textureNamed("ship")  // always uses 2x image
```

Answer (score 0):

apparently you need to have launch images set (in project settings) in order for xcode to recognize different screen sizes properly

Comment: I have exactly the same problem and setting launch images doesn't solve it. Do you have any other suppositions how to load 3x instead of 2x?

Comment: this is my way of loading images in spritekit.  look at my answer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27284856/spritekit-help-understanding-scaling/27364020#27364020

Comment: Yep, I store my images in a similar manner, but when it comes to texture atlas for iphone6+, 3x suffix is simply ignored: http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/download/file.php?id=2156

Comment: This answer should be unchecked, it's not correct, at least it does not work for me. I have spaceship.png, spaceship@2x.png, spaceship@3x.png in graphics.atlas folder but for iPhone 6 Plus it always loads the 2x one. Having a LaunchScreen.xib, so the iPhone 6 Plus launches with screen size of 414x736 points.

Comment: So did you get it to work some way? Or is it impossible to support 3x graphics using atlases?

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/28146685/… i followed this.. but even then my game didnt look right to me. I just used ended up using all the 2x assets for the iphone 6 plus and let it scale it for the bigger screen

Comment: Ok so this is a bug somewhere in SpriteKit/iOS... at least sounds like that. Maybe 3x can be loaded if we don't use atlases... but that would lose the atlas benefits.

Comment: Yes it's a bug in sprite kit

Comment: Just confirmed that using image asset catalogue, it does work (3x graphics are loaded correctly), but then we lose the benefits of atlases I guess. Sigh.

Comment: You mean xcassets vs texture assets?

Comment: Same thing here, iPhone 6+ simulator uses @2x images. I am using Xcode 6.1