# SpriteKit help understanding scaling

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

Making a portrait only game using SpriteKit and putting my image assets into `Images.xcassets`.  This is for iPhone, so my image assets are setup like so:

```
1x, 2x, Retina 4 2x, 3x
```

For example, under one image asset, a 2x, I have a 640x640 png, this fits fine on iPhone 4/4s, 5/5s but on 6 (which also scales @ 2x) it doesn't, because the 6 has a slightly wider screen @ 750px (or 375 points).  So I came-up with the following formula which I can pass into `[mySprite setScale:]` for each and every sprite I add to my scene.

```
CGFloat scale = screenPointWidth / (screenScale * 160)
```

Where `screenPointWidth = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width` and `screenScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]`.  `160` refers to a base 1x pixel width value (or `320/2`).  This returns a scale multiplayer.

With this multiplayer applied my 640x640 image scales and fits perfectly on a 750 wide screen.

**My questions**: is there a better way to do this, or am I doing it correct?  Is there a universal scaling setting I should be using instead, or should I just scale each and every sprite and sprite position based on my formula?  Or, should I **not** be using `Image.xcassets` and instead create individual .atlas' for specific screen resolutions?  Should I be concerned about upsampling and downsampling, or is that handled auto-magically by the iPhone 6/6+ itself?

Ref: http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iPhone 6 is close enough in resolution to iPhone 5 that it's meant to use 2x images.

1136 x 640 - iphone5

1334 x 750 - iphone 6

Because your background is 640 pixels tall, it will have some space missing on the top and bottom in portrait mode.  You need to make a background with areas that you don't mind being cut off on smaller devices (iphone 4 and 5).  Or you need to have a black frame around your game on the iphone 6. I wouldn't recommend scaling every image..

This was a common issue even before iphone 6 was around.  This image kind of shows what I'm talking about

http://cdn5.raywenderlich.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Aspect-Ratio-Diff.jpg

**Image Sizes**

You need three image sizes.

@2x = iphone4s, 5, 5s, 6  (you use this for non retina ipads as well)

@3x (1.5 * 2x)   = iphone 6 PLUS

@2x~ipad (2 * 2x) = ipad retina and retina mini

the way you want to organize this is up to you.  In my game I split my images up into two sets of atlases.  one for iPad and one for Iphone.

**My way of organizing my atlases**

Images with no suffix are for the non-retina ipads.

[image]

[image]

In my code I have a simple function to decide which texture atlas I want to load.

```
func getTextureAtlas(filename: String) -> SKTextureAtlas {
    var name = filename
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom != .Phone {
        name = "\(name)-ipad"
    }

    return SKTextureAtlas(named: name)
}
```

example useage:

```
shipAtlas = getTextureAtlas("ship")
```

Comment: Reg iPhone 6 and "just scales 2x images" -- does it actually scale them up, or are you meaning that 2x images simply fit within? Since I don't have a 6, I'm using the Sim to see how things look and nothing scales, although it does pull from my 2x assets (naturally).

Comment: I'm sorry I misread your original question.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: I see, so the practice is to make image assets larger so they (sorta) fit right on the varying screens?  In the case of @2x, I would make a 1136x640 (background example) and then load that on a 1024x768 and 960x640 device?  I think that's acceptable for images that may not matter so much, but if you need precise image, say a Chess Board, then it must fit or scale. In this case, if I use a 640x640 chess board, I can apply my formula to fit the sprite to screen precisely, as well, scale x,y positions.  Your answer adds value, but if having borders isn't desirable, scaling must be applied, agree?

Comment: Ray's image examples (your link) brings it home, thanks.

Comment: if you absolutely need 100% of the screen as a to-scale playable area then I suppose you need to use the scaling.  But in the case of a chessboard, I'd just have something like a background (a table or something) that the chessboard is sitting on, and isn't part of the playable area.

Comment: Ok, making sense now.  Appreciate.