# SpriteKit texture atlas for iphone 6 plus

Tags: ios, xcode6, sprite-kit, sktextureatlas

I've been trying to load a texture atlas for the iphone 6 plus but Xcode 6.2 does not generate one for the 3x images. It actually creates a texture atlas **without** the 3x prefix and the 2x images are used instead (I verified it by using a different content for the 3x image)

In my project I have a single folder named "sprites.atlas" containing the images for both 2x and 3x suffixes.

I read in SO ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28146685/spritekit-not-loading-3x-images-from-sktextureatlas) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25940788/sktextureatlas-and-3x-images)) about this issue but found only alternatives (like manually choosing the atlas) but I'm afraid this will shot back at later iOS versions as it feels incorrect.

Does anyone knows how to solve this? Does Xcode 6.3 solves this issue?

Comment: To my knowledge this is still a bug. As you said yourself, you can manually load up x3 images if you create your own texture atlas.

Comment: probably will. I just hate doing workarounds, especially for a trivial problem which should have been supported once the i6+ came out.